# Pass property to spring annotation from custom annotation

Tags: spring-boot, annotations

I have a custom annotation in spring, which levers the `@Retryable` annotation

```java
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Retryable(value = MyClass.SubClassException.class,
    backoff = @Backoff(random = true,
        delayExpression = "#{${retry.delayExpression}}",
        maxDelayExpression = "#{${retry.maxDelay}}",
        multiplierExpression = "#{${retry.multiplier}}"),
    maxAttemptsExpression = "#{${retry.maxRetryAttempts}}")
public @interface CustomRetryable {

  int delayMilliSeconds() default 1000;

  int maxDelayMilliSeconds() default 1000;

  int multiplier() default 2;

  int retryAttempts() default 3;

  Class<? extends Throwable>[] exceptionType();
}
```

What I would like to do, is to be able to call my annotation with a class and possibly a `readTimeout` and other values and have these passed to the `@Retryable` annotation. Is this possible?

I want to do something like this:

```java
@GlobalRetryable(exceptionType = MyCustom.SubClassException.class,
  delayMilliSeconds = 10)
Foo bar(Foozie request){
  // some impl heere
}
```

but I can't find a way of getting something like `MyCustom.SubClassException.class` passed to the `Retryable` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `@GlobalRetryable` and `@CustomRetryable` are the same, just a typo.

The annotation `@AliasFor` can be used for your requirement. This would be something like:

```
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Retryable(value = MyClass.SubClassException.class,
    backoff = @Backoff(random = true,
        delayExpression = "#{${retry.delayExpression}}",
        maxDelayExpression = "#{${retry.maxDelay}}",
        multiplierExpression = "#{${retry.multiplier}}"),
    maxAttemptsExpression = "#{${retry.maxRetryAttempts}}")
public @interface CustomRetryable {
  .....
  .....
  .....
  @AliasFor(annotation = Retryable.class, attribute = "value")
  Class<? extends Throwable>[] exceptionType();
}
```